# Mindbody GetClientServices

Tags: php, soap, mindbody

I've been navigating my way through the Mindbody API for a few days now, their php sample api implementation seems to have a couple of bugs here and there.

I've run across a mind block trying to get the specific services acquired by the user, I'm getting no error, just my whole page halts when accessing the function.

Code I'm running:

```
  $clientService = new MBClientService();
  $clientService->SetDefaultCredentials($creds);
  $clientService->SetDefaultUserCredentials($creds2);
  $clientService->GetClientServices($clientid, array(), array(29));
```

Things I've tried:

- Adding locationID array
- include the UserCredentials last minute.
- setting the program array and sessionTypeID array
- setting the clientID as an array

Hoping for someone's help. Thank you! It seems too simple, but I seem to be stuck in this. :|

Comment: Found the problem, ClassID is supposed to be part of the parameters! Also, UserCredentials is required.

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post it as an answer here and to accept it later yourself. While posting your question it could have helped to mention what was the library you were using and to post actual xml you're sending and receiving as a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * banarsiamin@gmail.com
 * @author Amin KHAN 
 */
/**
 * Provides route responses for the Example module.
 */
ini_set("user_agent", "FOOBAR");
class MINDBODY_API 
{
    /*
    *WSDL Is xml AND NWSDL simple 
    */
    public $appointmentServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/AppointmentService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $appointmentServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/AppointmentService.asmx";
    public $classServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $classServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx";
    public $clientServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $clientServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx";
    public $dataServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/DataService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $dataServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/DataService.asmx";
    public $finderServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/FinderService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $finderServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/FinderService.asmx";
    public $saleServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/SaleService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $saleServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/SaleService.asmx";
    public $siteServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/SiteService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $siteServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/SiteService.asmx";
    public $staffServiceWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/StaffService.asmx?WSDL";
    public $staffServiceNWSDL = "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/StaffService.asmx";

    private $client;
    private $sourceCredentials = array("SourceName"=>'banarsiamin', "Password"=>'123456=', "SiteIDs"=>array('-9999'));
    private $userCredentials = array("Username"=>'Siteowner', "Password"=>'apitest1234', "SiteIDs"=>array('-9999'));

    // CLASS SERVICE //
    function getClasses($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient( $this->classServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 
        'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->classServiceNWSDL,
       "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {
            $result = $this->client->GetClasses(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    //  GetClassSchedules : - Gets a list of class schedules.  //
    function getClassSchedules($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient( $this->classServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->classServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {
            $result = $this->client->GetClassSchedules(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }


    function getXMLRequest() {
        return $this->client->__getLastRequest();
    }

    function getXMLResponse() {

        return $this->client->__getLastResponse();
    }

    /*************************************
     *  Staff Service
     *  Provides methods and attributes relating to staff.
     *  The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.
     **********************************************************************************************************/

    /*
    *   AddOrUpdateStaff :-  Add or update staff.1712 16894
    */
    function addOrUpdateStaff($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->staffServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'Test'=>FALSE, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->staffServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try { 
                $result = $this->client->AddOrUpdateStaff(array("Request"=>$request)); 
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $s) {  echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;} 
        catch (Exception $e) {  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  }
        return $result;
    }
    /*
    *   GetStaff :-  Gets a list of staff members.
    */
    function getStaff($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->staffServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->staffServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try { 
                $result = $this->client->GetStaff(array("Request"=>$request)); 
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $s) {echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;} 
        catch (Exception $e) {  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  }
        return $result;
    }
    /*  
    *   GetStaffImgURL :- Gets a staff member's image URL if it exists.
    */
    function getStaffImgURL($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->staffServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->staffServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try { 
                $result = $this->client->GetStaffImgURL(array("Request"=>$request)); 
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $s) {echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;} 
        catch (Exception $e) {  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  }
        return $result;
    }
    /*
    *   GetStaffPermissions :- Gets a list of staff permissions based on the given staff member.
    */
    function getStaffPermissions($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->staffServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->staffServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try { 
                $result = $this->client->GetStaffPermissions(array("Request"=>$request)); 
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $s) {echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;} 
        catch (Exception $e) {  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  }
        return $result;
    }
    /*
    *   ValidateStaffLogin :-  Validates a username and password. This method returns the staff on success. 
    */
    function validateStaffLogin($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->staffServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->staffServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try { 
                $result = $this->client->ValidateStaffLogin(array("Request"=>$request)); 
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $s) {echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;} 
        catch (Exception $e) {  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  }
        return $result;
    }

    /**************END STAFF******************/

    /***************************************************/
    /**************Appointments STAFF******************/
    /*************************************************/

    //  GetStaffAppointments :- Gets a list of appointments that a given staff member is instructing. //
    function GetStaffAppointments($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->appointmentServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->appointmentServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));

        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);

        try 
        {

            $result = $this->client->GetStaffAppointments(array("Request"=>$request));

        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    //  GetClassSchedules : - Gets a list of class schedules.  //
    function getScheduleItems($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->appointmentServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->appointmentServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {
            $result = $this->client->GetScheduleItems(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    //  GetBookableItems  : - Gets a list of class schedules.     //
    function getBookableItems($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->appointmentServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->appointmentServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {  // $client->GetActivationCode(array("Request"=>$request));
            $result = $this->client->GetBookableItems (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /*AddOrUpdateAppointments  :- Adds or updates a list of appointments.*/
    function addUpdateAppointments($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->appointmentServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->appointmentServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {
            $result = $this->client->AddOrUpdateAppointments(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* AddOrUpdateAvailabilities :- Adds or updates a list of availabilities.*/
    function addUpdateAvailabilities($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->appointmentServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->appointmentServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {    
            $result = $this->client->AddOrUpdateAvailabilities(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /************** END Appointments STAFF******************/

    /************** START Service******************/

    /* AddOrUpdateContactLogs   :- Add or update client contact logs..*/
        function AddOrUpdateContactLogs ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1,'location'=>$this->clientServiceNWSDL, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->AddOrUpdateContactLogs (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* GetClients :- Gets a list of clients..*/
    function getClients($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        //$result = $client->GetActivationCode(array("Request"=>$request));
        try {
            $result = $this->client->GetClients(array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /* GetClientIndexes  :-Gets a list of currently available client indexes.*/
    function GetClientIndexes ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->GetClientIndexes (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* GetClientPurchases   :-Get purchases for a client.*/
    function GetClientPurchases ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->GetClientPurchases (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* GetClientVisits    :-Get purchases for a client.*/
    function GetClientVisits ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->GetClientVisits (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* GetClientServices     :-Get purchases for a client.*/
    function getClientServices ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->GetClientServices (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /* AddOrUpdateClients     :-Get purchases for a client.*/
    function addOrUpdateClients ($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->clientServiceWSDL, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->clientServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try {
            $result = $this->client->AddOrUpdateClients (array("Request"=>$request));
        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /************** END Service******************/

    /***************************************************/
    /**************Site *******************************/
    /*************************************************/

    //  GetSites :- Gets a list of appointments that a given staff member is instructing. //
    function getSites($params = array()) {
        $this->client = new soapClient( $this->siteServiceWSDL, array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>FALSE, "location" => $this->siteServiceNWSDL,
         "stream_context" => stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=> false,'allow_self_signed' => FALSE)))));
        $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$this->sourceCredentials, "UserCredentials"=>$this->userCredentials),$params);
        try 
        {
            $result = $this->client->GetSites(array("Request"=>$request));

        } catch (SoapFault $s) {
                echo 'ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
echo "<PRE>";
$mindb              = new MINDBODY_API(); 
$staff          = array('UpdateAction'=>'AddNew',
                    'Clients'=>array( 
                        'Client'=>array(
                        'FirstName'=>'amin',
                        'LastName'=>'khan',
                        'Username'=> 'banarsiamin',
                        'Password'=> 'amin1216$1',
                        'Email'=>'banarsiamin@gmail.com',
                        'MobilePhone'=>'9770534045',
                        'HomePhone'=>'9770534045',
                        'WorkPhone'=>'9770534045',
                        'Address'=>'aminkhanb',
                        'Address2'=>'aminkhanb',
                        'City'=>'aminkhanb',
                        'State'=>'CA',
                        'Country'=>'US',
                        'PostalCode'=>'93401',
                        'ForeignZip'=>'333',
                        'Bio'=>'aminkhanb'
                        )
                    )
                );
    $mail               = 'banarsiamin@gmail.com';
    echo"<BR>";
    //  $addstaff       = $mindb->addOrUpdateClients($staff); // Add Client 
    $result1        = $mindb->getClients(array ('SearchText'=>''));//'SearchText'=>$mail // Get All Cleint
//  print_r($result1);
    $ClientMembers1 = $result1->GetClientsResult;
    //print_r($ClientMembers1);
    $Client1        = $ClientMembers1->Clients;`enter code here`
    //print_r($Client1);
    $getAllClient1  = $Client1->Client;
    print_r($getAllClient1);
?>
```