# mindbody api post CustomClientFields

Tags: mindbody

Im using the API class from [Mindbody GetClientServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865644/mindbody-getclientservices) to access the MindBody Api. Works great.

Now i need to add custom values to the client defined in the Mindbody CMS (ie exmployer)

So this is the array i am using:

```
array('UpdateAction'=>'Update',
 'Clients'=>array( 
  'Client'=>array(
   'ID'=>'100015637',
   'FirstName'=>'dummy'.$i,
   'LastName'=>'Galaxy'.$i,
   'BirthDate'=>'2010-05-24T18:13:00', //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899332/not-a-valid-allxsd-value
   'Username'=> 'helloDummy1'.$i,
   'Password'=> 'amin1216$1'.$i,
   'Email'=>'dummy'.$i.'@noblestreet.eu',
   'EmailOptIn'=> new SoapVar('true', XSD_STRING, 'xsd:boolean'),
   'SendEmail'=> new SoapVar('true', XSD_STRING, 'xsd:boolean'),
   'MobilePhone'=>'9770534045',
   'HomePhone'=>'9770534045',
   'WorkPhone'=>'9770534045',
   'Address'=>'dummy'.$i,
   'Address2'=>'dummy'.$i,
   'City'=>'dummy'.$i,
   'State'=>'ZH',
   'Country'=>'NL',
   'PostalCode'=>'2511HA',
   'ForeignZip'=>'2511HA',
   'Bio'=>'dummy'.$i,
   'Status'=>'active',
   'CustomClientFields' => array(
    'CustomClientField'=> array(
      0 => array(
        'ID' => '1',
        'value'=>'test'
      )
    )
   )
  )
 )
);
```

On posting this to the API the customfield doesnt get added and i cant see it in the MB cms.

Any help on this one?

btw inserting/updating other values works

Comment: 1) Post resulting XML request you're sending to Mindbody API. 2) Try comparing your XML to the example XML updating custom fields shown on https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Develop/ClientService. 3) Which XML response do you get? You may get an error, I suppose. 4) Most probably you need to send 'Value' not 'value'. 5) Make sure you send  <Fields>
               <string>Clients.CustomClientFields</string>
            </Fields> in your XML request

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was point 4. Bad mistake on my part, it needed to be Value. I didnt notice it, but rereading everything i corrected the typo and indeed it works.

Comment: You didn't give me a chance to post my answer as my answer.

Comment: My mistake, you posted it as a comment, so i couldnt mark it as the correct reply. Hence my reply below to give you the credit.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment made by Yuga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855640/mindbody-api-post-customclientfields/45898752#comment78748203_45855640) was the correct answer:

> 1) Post resulting XML request you're sending to Mindbody API.
>
> 2) Try comparing your XML to the example XML updating custom fields shown on https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Develop/ClientService.
>
> 3) Which XML response do you get? You may get an error, I suppose.
>
> 4) Most probably you need to send 'Value' not 'value'.
>
> 5) Make sure you send  `<Fields><string>Clients.CustomClientFields</string></Fields>` in your XML request

Point 4 (correcting the typo `value` to `Value`) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me we need to provide additional information like the below.

```
CustomclientFields

ID
DataType
Name
Value
```

Here is the example

```
'CustomClientFields' => array( 'CustomClientField'=> array( 
0 => array('ID' => 1, 'DataType' => 'Number', 'Name' => 'txtCustom1', 'Value'=>121212121212, ), 
1 => array('ID' => 2, 'DataType' => 'Number', 'Name' => 'txtCustom2', 'Value'=>121212, ), 
2 => array('ID' => 3, 'DataType' => 'Text', 'Name' => 'txtCustom3', 'Value'=>Sampletext, ) )
```